# cannot output the last row with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, put

```
void reverse_output(string s, fstream& file, streamoff initial_pos)
{
    const char* a = s.c_str();
    file.seekp(initial_pos, ios::beg);
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        file.put(a[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    string file_name = "E:\\WorkSpace\\ConsoleApplication2\\Debug\\2.txt";
    fstream file;
    file.open(file_name.c_str());

    string row;
    streamoff pos = 0;


    while (getline(file, row))
    {       
        reverse_output(row, file, pos);
        file.put('\n');
        pos = file.tellp();
        file.seekg(pos, ios::beg);
    }

    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to write a program which reverse each row of a file.
Say a file which contains:

```
123456
qwe
```

will be converted to the same file contains:

```
654321
ewq
```

I have written the above codes but they won't work for the last row.
I suspect

```
while (getline(file, row))
```

is the main reason.  Who could help me and tell me the real reason?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: since switching between input and output is done with an intervening seek operation that's actually fine. The code writes as many characters as it reads and it seeks back to the start of the respective line. The issue is merely that seeking fails when any state bit, including `std::ios_base::eofbit` is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `while (std::getline(file, row))` is OK. Your issue is that the last line of your file doesn't contain a newline! When reading the last line, its end is determined by touching the end of the file. When the stream touches the end of the file, the flag `std::ios_base::eofbit` gets set, i.e., `file.eof()` yields `true`.

The next operation you do is trying to seek the stream using `file.seekp(...)`. The call to `seekp()` creates a `std::ostream::sentry` on the file which will convert to `false` when `file.good()` is `false`. Having `std::ios_base::eofbit` set causes `file.good()` to be `false`. When the `sentry` object converts to `false` the seek operation fails and `std::ios_base::failbit` gets set.

The easiest fix to the problem is to reset `std::ios_base::eofbit` at the start of the `while`-loop:

```
while (getline(file, row))
{       
    file.clear();
    // ...
}
```

Since the stream returned from `std::getline()` converted to `true`, only `std::ios_base::eofbit` can be set anyway: if either `std::ios_base::failbit` or `std::ios_base::badbit` had been set, the stream would convert to `false`.

Comment: Thank you!  Your explanation does help me a lot.